# Android viewGroup listen to child view visibility changes

Tags: android

I have an android custom `ViewGroup`

I need to receive children `visibility` changes and then make some change to my logic and ...

for example: I set `view1` in a `RelativeLayout` above `view2` and when `view2` set it's `visibility` to `GONE` I must change `view1` design roles and ...

Answer (score 3):

In your custom `ViewGroup`, you might have overriden `onLayout()` and `onMeasure()`. Inside these methods you could just get how many child are there and they visibility status.

```
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
             final View child = getChildAt(i);
             if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                 // Measure the child or do whatever you want
             }
        }
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html. There is an example in that page.

Comment: The code i have in my answer is the simple code. You said you `need to receive children visibility changes`, and this is how you get it. After this, you need to make the logic ready.

Comment: No, I need to detect when children change their visibility not get their visibility. for example in linearlayout when a child GONE the others fills it's space and layout resizes

Comment: The moment the visibility of the child changes, the `onLayout()` method of the `ViewGroup` gets called.

Comment: thanks. is it possible to change layouts visibility in its onLayout method. I mean change own visibility not childrens (in this line)

Comment: Yes you can change the visibility of the layout. For better understanding about `onLayout()` see the about link in the answer, or this one: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/05/android-custom-layout/

Comment: setVisibility() method can be used for changing